# Play! 2.1 Forms broken after updating a Play! 2.0 app

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

The simple code snippet speaks for itself.

```
[error]   Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
[error]                             ^
[error]   symbol:   method form()
[error]   location: class Form
```

I've checked documentation : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaForms

Doesn't understand what's going on...

The documentation is clear about that :

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Migration

and the Java API is clear too :

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/java/play/data/Form.html#form(java.lang.Class)

Comment: I wouldn't say it "speaks for itself". What kind of error message is that? Are there no other details?

Comment: nothing. I'm not a scala dev so I'm not sure but I can't see form() method in play! source code : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/java/play/data/Form.html#form(java.lang.Class)
How is generated the javadoc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `form` method has been moved in version 2.1.

Check that you are actually using `play.data.Form.form()` (it was previsously in `play.mvc.Controller.Form` if I remember well).

If you did change that, try a `play clean clean-all` and re-run a compilation. It should work then...

Comment: already done play clean command. play run wasn't enough. play compile command solve the problem. It's a very bad behaviour in my sense. nothing about that in the migration guide.

Comment: I agree with you. Play! 2 documentation is far too light. A way to sell more books?

Answer (score 4):

```
Form<User> userForm = form(User.class);
```

**OR**

```
DynamicForm requestData = form().bindFromRequest();
```

Shifting from play 2.0.x to 2.1.x gives error for above code.

**solution:**

play.data.Form.* is a static import.

use `import static play.data.Form.*;` in your file & error will get resolved.